# Checking for None value while parsing a XML

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am parsing a XML file. I need to check for series_id field.
But i am unable to find a condition where the value is not there. Tried None, len(has_series) = 0 but it never gives me a value. Even i tried to check for False and " ". But not able to validate the condition.

My Snippet below

```
has_series = program.xpath('props/*[@title="Series_ID"]')
if has_series is None:
    print "None Value"
if len(has_series) ==0:
    print "Zero value"
if has_series == False:
    series_id = "N"
else:
    series_id = has_series[0].text
    print series_id
```

Part from the XML without has_series

```
<para352 title="Series_ID"></para352>
```

I need to find a check for no value. The output comes like this.

```
Processing: /tmp/rosh/dummy/30000000550321045_2019_10_22T19_49_13Z.xml


Processing: /tmp/rosh/dummy/30000000550324403_2019_10_22T19_49_13Z.xml


Processing: /tmp/rosh/dummy/30000000550324407_2019_10_22T19_49_13Z.xml


Processing: /tmp/rosh/dummy/E30000001555205318_2019_10_09T12_19_38Z.xml
XN016663
Processing: /tmp/rosh/dummy/E30000001555205320_2019_10_09T12_19_38Z.xml
XN016663
Processing: /tmp/rosh/dummy/E30000001555332469_2019_10_09T12_19_38Z.xml
XN016663
```

wherever the values are picked, script displays it properly. But i need to validate against a non value condition.

Comment: Please can you edit your code to provide a [mre] (I should be able to paste it into a file and run it without adding anything!) because a snippet is pretty useless when wondering why your code isn’t working. Also provide a couple of short XML examples preferably as literal strings in the code that is the same structure as your XML and has opportunities for absence of title.

Comment: ThIs is only a theory because I can’t execute your snippet. Logically the only opportunity for your code snippet not to print anything is if `is_series==False` is True, so presumably that’s what is happening. Confirm that very easily by simply printing has_series.

Comment: I found an answer by using isapha(). If its false, i get the value i wanted

Answer (score 0):

By using series_id.isalnum(), i could check for a null value.